# Is Neo4jClient compatible for Memgraph?

Tags: .net, neo4jclient, memgraphdb

I am working on analyzing the transition a Dot Net Core application(which uses Neo4jClient ) from Neo4J database to memgraph database. Can anyone help me if Neo4jClient can be used for Memgraph or a custom implementation needs to be done for cypher query creation ? Any references is appreciated.

Tried connecting to a docker instance Memgraph. Facing errors while going through Neo4Client connection.
Expected just a connection string and few syntax changes for Memgraph

Comment: Hi @sriram g,  so Neo4jClient C# can be used to connect to Memgraph, and interventions should be minimal; most of the drivers Memgraph depends on are Neo4j drivers.  We are currently in the process of updating our C# documentation; here is the version we now have: https://memgraph.com/docs/client-libraries/c-sharp.
This should get you connected and started with Memgraph and Neo4j driver. 
Can you provide more details of what issue you are experiencing and maybe a code snippet for connecting? 

That way, I can help you with the exact issue you are experiencing.